# How to write dataframe to csv WITHOUT removing commas

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a df with only one column as follows:

```
       'id'
0     11,20
1     12,25
2     13,30
3     14,35
4     15,40
```

When I tried to this df to csv:
`df("ids.csv",sep=',',header=None)`, the comma is gone. Opening csv looks like this:

```
0     1120
1     1225
2     1330
3     1435
4     1540
```

`df("ids.csv",sep='\t',header=None)`, the comma is also gone and it separates to two columns. Opening csv looks like this:

```
0      11  20
1      12  25
2      13  30
3      14  35
4      15  40
```

How can I save the csv exactly like the df format (like the following format)?

```
0     11,20
1     12,25
2     13,30
3     14,35
4     15,40
```

Comment: It is weird, `df("ids.csv",sep=',',header=None)` should working nice. What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: @jezrael print (df.head().to_dict()) is {'id': {0: '11,20', 1: '12,25', 2: '13,30', 3: '14,35', 4: '15,40'}}

Comment: For me it working nice `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '11,20', 1: '12,25', 2: '13,30', 3: '14,35', 4: '15,40'}})

df.to_csv('ids.csv', sep=',',header=None)`

Comment: @jezrael mine is not working. If I have "$" replaced "," then "$" can stay in the csv file. Strange.

Comment: How do you test file? In some text editor like `notepad++` ? Or in excel?

Comment: i tested the csv file with excel

Comment: As your data separates the digits of the numbers with a comma, it may not be the best idea to use it also as a separator. You can use `|` for example. And, you'll be better off opening the file with a notepad to check it, as Excel can some times mess up csv files

Comment: It's strange that with sep ="," if I read the file in notepad it looks fine; however open it in excel it does not include comma. is it normal?